# player vs computer NIM game

Tags: javascript

I have to do a human vs. computer game where each player removes a number of straws (1,2 or 3) and the player who removes the last straw wins.
The number of straws is randomly generated between 15 and 30, and whenever the computer plays it has to use (if possible) the winning strategy meaning : if number of straws MOD 4 !== 0, then computer removes the rest which is number of straws MOD 4, else computer randomly removes 1, 2 or 3 straws.
This is what I have done so far. I do not know how to code the human vs. computer part. Shall I create a string for player and computer? Shall I leave it as it is meaning calling the 2 different functions while clicking on the buttons (‘oui’ or ‘non’) depending on who starts first? Is there not a risk of redundancy of the functions? or is there another possibility? Any help would be appreciated. :)

```js
var numDuplicates = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) + 15;
var player;
var computer;


function generateNumbers() {
  var theBoard = document.getElementById("board");
  for (let dup = 0; dup < numDuplicates; dup++) {
    var toDup = document.createElement("img");
    toDup.setAttribute("src", "img/allumette.png");
    toDup.setAttribute("alt", "flamme");
    theBoard.appendChild(toDup);
  }
  return document.getElementById("random-number").value = numDuplicates;
}
```

```html
<body id="thebody" onload="generateNumbers()">

  <h1>Projet du module Scripts clients</h1>
  <hr />
  <h2>Jeu des allumettes</h2>
  <div id="rules">
    <h3>Règles du jeu :</h3>
    <p>Ce jeu se joue contre l'ordinateur. Les joueurs disposent d’un nombre d’allumettes tiré de manière aléatoire, entre 15 et 30. Tour à tour, les joueurs prennent un nombre d’allumettes compris entre 1 et 3. Le gagnant est celui qui prend la dernière
      allumette.
      <br /> Il convient de sélectionner celui qui doit commencer la partie, après que le nombre d'allumettes ait été généré.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="board"></div>
  <input id="random-number" value="" />
  <label> allumettes ont été générées.</label>

  <h4 id="start">Souhaitez-vous commencer en premier ?</h4>
  <button type="button" onclick="player">oui</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="computer">non</button>
</body>
```